# How to share directory in Ubuntu22.04 for Windows users

Tags: networking, samba

I have a Windows domain LAN + some Ubuntu 22.04.
I'd like to share Ubuntu folder to make it accessible to Everyone from Windows domain.
I have made this recommendation:

https://www.debugpoint.com/guide-how-share-folder-between-ubuntu-linux-windows/

After it I view the shared folder in windows

```
\\myubuntu
   \media
```

But I cannot open it in windows, it writes me:
You do not have permissions to access \myubuntu\media

How to share it for any windows user?
P.S. smb.config
contains

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP # <-- maybe need to change it?
```

I have added these strings:

```
[media]
path = /home/xoleg/media
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
force user = guest # <-- maybe need to change it?
guest ok = yes
```

Comment: Try this: delete the `force user` and `guest ok` lines, and add a line `valid users = myuser` where `myuser` is a Ubuntu user. Restart samba (`sudo systemctl restart smbd`) and try to access the `\\myubuntu\media` folder.

Comment: Ok, thanx, will try it just now. Yet another: do I need to change workgroup = WORKGROUP to domain name?

Comment: Hi @Jos, I have made all you wrote. But again permissions problem: windows cannot open the folder.

Comment: YES! it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> [media]
> path = /home/xoleg/media
> browsable = yes
> writable = yes
> read only = no
> force user = guest # <-- maybe need to change it?
> guest ok = yes
> ```

Is xoleg a user name on this linux system?

If it is and you're running ubuntu 22.04 no user local or network will be able to access anything in that user's home directory.

If you truly want a guest accessible share you need to change `force user = guest` to `force user = xoleg`

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: Yes, xoleg - is my user accnt.

Comment: Also, may be it is better to share some other folder not in my home dir?

Comment: You can but you would still need to use the force user = xoleg operator in your share definition. If you don't - on a guest accessible share - all files added by the guest would be uneditable to xoleg.

Comment: And yet another:  do I need to change workgroup = WORKGROUP to domain name?

Comment: [media]
path = /home/xoleg/media
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
valid user = xoleg
force user = xoleg

The same permissions problem

Comment: It's "valid users" not "valid user" and if you use "valid users" you don't need "force user". You do need to add that user to the samba password database however. You do that with this command: `sudo smbpasswd -a xoleg`

Comment: Thank you @Morbius1, finally it works!

Comment: I have 2 windows domains (one direction (partially) trusted relationships) and the Ubuntu machine What should I write in workgroup = ? Can I write here 2 domain names?

Comment: What is interesting: from one Windows machine user has access to the shared folder but from other  Windows machine (the same windows user) - has no access; permissions problem. What can it be?