# Share directory in Ubuntu22.04 for Windows users: not all users have access

Tags: permissions, samba

I have made as described there
[How to share directory in Ubuntu22.04 for Windows users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1494441/how-to-share-directory-in-ubuntu22-04-for-windows-users)

Finally I can access from Windows station to the shared folder (Ubuntu). Great.
But the same windows user on other machine has no access to the folder: permissions.
Yet another user from other windows machine has no access too.
All these machines are in the same LAN.

That is changed part of my smb.conf

[media]
path = /home/xlg/media
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
#valid users = xlg
force user = xlg
#guest ok = yes

[storm]
path = /media/xlg$ cd 36c437d7-81a3-4461-bd61-3b5c892f7cfe/storm
#browsable = yes
#writable = yes
read only = no
#valid users = xlg
force user = xlg
guest ok = Yes

What to check and fix?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the elements of the solution you've tried in the post itself rather than relying on a link to the guide you followed. We need to understand what steps you took specifically and the error messages you got in the process as they will help us better diagnose your problem.  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].